# Show div for only one locale on Symfony3 with translation

Tags: internationalization, symfony

I'm working on a project using Symfony3. This project has 3 different languages.

We are using Translations and it is working perfectly fine. However there is a tutorial page and there is one instruction that is only valid for Brazil.
I would like to see this  only when the locale pt_BR is selected.
Is there a way I can do something like:

```
~my translated content~
if(locale==pt_BR){  <div>Content only for Brazil</div> }
~my translated content~
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I though of the solution 20 minutes after posting.

On my action

```
 public function myAction(Request $request){
    $locale = $request->getLocale();

    return $this->render('foo/index.html.twig', array(
        'locale' => $locale
    ));
}
```

On my view

```
{% if locale=='pt_BR' %}
    my content
{% endif %}
```

I guess is not a good idea work overnight. This is so dumb.

Comment: Edit.
There is no need to send locale on render view. 
on twig just use app.request.locale